# codeigniter4 CSRF error: "The action you have requested is not allowed."

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I create a login page . when I reload login page after click submit,
it display :
[image: The action you requested is not allowed]

why?

this is my route :
`$routes->get('login', [Login::class, 'index'],['as' => 'user_login']);`
`$routes->post('login/signIn', [Login::class,'signIn']);`
And my controler code

```
public function signIn()
    {
        helper('form');
        $session = session();
        $model = model(UserModel::class);
        $username = $this->request->getVar('username');
        $password = $this->request->getVar('password');
        $data = $model->where('username', $username)->first();

        if($data){
            $pass = $data['password'];
            if($pass == $password){
                $ses_data = [
                    'user_id'       => $data['id'],
                    'username'      => $data['username'],
                    'email'         => $data['email'],
                    'logged_in'     => TRUE
                ];
                $session->set($ses_data);
                return redirect()->to('/');
            }else{
                $session->setFlashdata('msg', 'Wrong Password');
                return view('templates/header')
                . view('login')
                . view('templates/footer');
            }
        }else{
            $session->setFlashdata('msg', 'username not Found');
            return view('templates/header')
                . view('login')
                . view('templates/footer');
        }
    }
```

**also** , if password or username  is  fake.  the url cannot back to `/login`,still is  `/login/signIn`

Answer (score 1):

The error you get comes from CI's CSRF-protection. I guess you are not opening your login form element with CI's `form`-helper (`<?=form_opne()?>`) nor inserting the csrf token via `<?=csrf_field()?>` ([Further reading](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/security.html?highlight=csrf#html-forms))?
You need to do that or disable CSRF-protection in the config (NOT recommended).

Furthermore to fix you second error you have to redirect to login and not display your login view in the `signIn()`-method:

```php
return redirect()->to('user_login');
```

This will (assuming this route renders the login view) show the login form on the `/login` url.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can be useful or maybe not. If I use CI4 `from_open()` it creates a from with `action="http://localhost/example"` (baseURL automaticaly added) and I got

`CodeIgniter\Security\Exceptions\SecurityException #403`.

If I create form manually without baseURL action="/example" I don't have SecurityException #403